# the value becomes NaN in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, numbers

I try to iterate over the collection like the following

```
var debitAmountTcyTotal = 0;
var debitAmountPcyTotal = 0;
            _.each(JournalVoucherView.journalVoucherDebitCollection.models, function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    debitAmountTcyTotal = parseFloat(debitAmountTcyTotal) + parseFloat(data.get("amountTcy"));
                    debitAmountPcyTotal = parseFloat(debitAmountPcyTotal) + parseFloat(data.get("amountPcy"));
                }
            });

            $('#journalvoucher-debit-amountTcy-total').text(parseFloat(debitAmountTcyTotal));
            $('#journalvoucher-debit-amountPcy-total').text(parseFloat(debitAmountPcyTotal));
```

but when the collection is having no value the following becomes `NaN`

```
debitAmountTcyTotal
debitAmountPcyTotal
```

but i have initialized the above variables with `zero` why is it becoming as NaN when i set it to `zero` ?

I really don't understand the reason behind.

I use [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

Comment: parseFloat('zero') will always return NaN. Why not 0? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your zero value with

```
debitAmountTcyTotal = parseFloat(debitAmountTcyTotal) + parseFloat(data.get("amountTcy"));
```

Presumably `parseFloat(data.get("amountTcy"))` is `NaN`

`0 + NaN` is `NaN`

Comment: The call will not even go to the above place when the collection is empty in which case how this line could be excuted ?

Comment: Maybe the collection isn't empty but contains data you don't expect. The test case you've provided is going to throw reference errors, so it clearly isn't complete. Try inserting a break point and tracing through the code line by line to watch what happens to the variables.

Answer (score 2):

99% `data.get("amountTcy")` resturns `NaN` or value, which could not be converted to number. And normal value (zero) + NaN is always a NaN.

Furthermore you don't need to call parseFloat on value which is already a number (e.g. `debitAmountTcyTotal`).